# Vuze not starting?

Tags: debian, software-installation, bittorrent

```
root@debian:/home/love# vuze
Starting Azureus...
Suitable java version found [java = java 1.7.0_111]
Configuring environment...
Java exec found in PATH. Verifying...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gudy.azureus2.platform.unix.ScriptBeforeStartup
Loading Azureus:
java -Xmx256m -cp "./*.jar" -Djava.library.path="/usr/bin" -Dazureus.install.path="/usr/bin" -Dazureus.script="/usr/bin/vuze" -Dazureus.script.version=6 org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main
Exit from Azureus complete
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gudy.azureus2.platform.unix.ScriptAfterShutdown
Azureus TERMINATED.
```

Following steps were taken to install vuze:

```
$ wget http://cf1.vuze.com/files/VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2
$ tar -xjvf VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/vuze*
$ sudo mv vuze /opt/vuze
$ sudo ln -sf /opt/vuze/vuze /usr/bin/vuze
```

Comment: Use other torrent client which is already in package.

Comment: 1. Why in the world are you running something like `vuze` as root!? 2. What is the output of `type vuze`? Are you sure you're running the one in `/opt` and not something else? I just ran the exact same commands you give in your question and could load vuze (as root, even!) with no errors.